# Number of rational points over finite fields mod $q$ is birational invariant

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, birational-geometry

I heard that if $\mathbf F_q$ is a finite field, $X, Y$ are birational smooth proper variety over $\mathbf F_q$, then $\#(X(\mathbf F_q)) \equiv \#(Y(\mathbf F_q)) \pmod q$, and I heard that the proof uses crystalline cohomology. Anyone could explain the proof, or is there a reference, thanks.

Comment: This is not true. The projective plane and the plane blown up at a point are a counterexample. They probably meant the number of rational points mod $q$ or something like that.

Comment: @Sawin I'm sorry, fixed it.

Comment: See http://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/number-of-points-modulo-q-is-a-stable-birational-invariant/

Comment: @Rössler Thanks very much. By the way, the reference Sur le groupe fondamental d’une variété unirationelle mentioned in the link, I couldn't find this article on the internet, is there an online version of it.

Comment: @越谷あおい https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z1sBvkv7ZRihZhuznbR3vWol2Nuoee1z/view?usp=sharing although I believe you can find old comptes rendus papers officially somewhere